# how to remove reference format in ACM?

Tags: cross-referencing, acm

I am using the ACM format but somehow I am getting my own paper as Reference format. Here is [a link to the image](https://postimg.org/image/7pkgepu31/) (stackexchange won't let me upload it)

I wish someone could help! Thanks!

Comment: Found the answer: Add the line: 
\settopmatter{printacmref=false} % Removes citation information below abstract

after \documentclass